# How to get a unique identifier for a device running a flutter web app?

Tags: flutter

I would like to get a unique identifier like a mac address for a desktop machine running my flutter web app.

Something similar to device Id for ioS and Android. I have tried all the available plugins but none of them return a value and I was wondering if there is such feature or is this still missing from Flutter Web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in Flutter Web as it is compiled to JavaScript and it is not possible to get machine identifiable information such as a MAC address as that would be a security and privacy risk to obtain that information from the browser. You could try creating your own identifier using [uuid](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid) or something similar depending on your exact use case. However; such a solution would not be permanent and users would get a new identifier when their browser cache is cleared.

Comment: Thank you .. this is what I found out as well.