# Flutter Web UUID Unique Identifier

Tags: flutter, web, get, uuid, identifier

How can I get UUID in Flutter Web.
I need some unique identifier in order to keep record of devices useb by customer,my testing device,develeper device.

In android, I'm using device_info_plugin.

How can I get Unique identifier in Web?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [platform_device_id](https://pub.dev/packages/platform_device_id) to get the browser details.

For browser info, you can use it as

```
import 'package:platform_device_id/platform_device_id.dart';
String? deviceId = await PlatformDeviceId.getDeviceId;
print($deviceId);
```

OR

hare is the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977372/how-to-get-a-unique-identifier-for-a-device-running-a-flutter-web-app) to the approach to set a custom uuid for flutter web

Comment: Is userAgent is unique?

Comment: For unique, you should use webBrowserInfo.productSub. I have updated the code

Comment: productSub is also same. I tested it with 4 different machine. Its showing same. 20030107

Comment: you can look at all the values given by the webBrowserInfo and select any unique value. `webBrowserInfo.toMap()`

Comment: All property are same.